# 404 error - unable to find JSON file when making a map but it looks like it's in the right place

Tags: json, d3.js

I'm trying to make a map of Austin, TX (and eventually use it for a D3.js project) but I'm having trouble getting the map to appear. I have a .json file that I am reading into the following program, but I get this error in my console:

http://localhost:8000/practice/code/austinshapefiles/tract2.json 404 (File not found)

I have verified that the tract2.json file is in the correct place. Here is my html map file, which has path http://localhost:8000/documents/d3js_projects/practice/code/austinmap.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

</style>

<body>
<script src="..//d3/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="..//d3/topojson.js"></script>

<script>

/* JavaScript goes here. */

var width = 1200,
    height = 550;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    scatterwidth = width - margin.left - margin.right,
    scatterheight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width*.5]);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height*.9, 0]);

  var svg1 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", scatterwidth + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", scatterheight + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


d3.json("/practice/code/austinshapefiles/tract2.json", function(error, json, centroid) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);
  console.log(json);  
  var subunits = topojson.feature(json, json.objects.tract);

  var mapg = svg1.append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate("+width*.2+",0)")
    .attr("id", "mapg");

  var projection = d3.geo.albers()
      .center([0, 30.2500])
      .rotate([97.7500,0])
      .scale(height*100)
      .translate([width/2, height/2]) ;  
  var path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection) ; 
  mapg.append("path")
      .datum(subunits)
  var tryme ; 
  mapg.selectAll(".subunit")
      .data(topojson.feature(json, json.objects.tract).features)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("id", function(d) {return "tract"+d.id.substring(9,21);})
        .attr("fill", "rgb(256,256,256)")
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", .1)
        ;

    //add the centroid circles 
     mapg.selectAll(".subunit")
      .data(topojson.feature(json, json.objects.tract).features)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "point")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", "green")
        .attr("id", function(d){return "centroid"+d.id.substring(9,21);})
        .attr("visibility", "hidden")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")"; }) ; 

    mapg.selectAll(".subunit")
    .data(topojson.feature(json, json.objects.tract).features)
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .attr("id", function(d){return "tooltip"+d.tractfull.substring(9,21);})
        .attr("transform", function(d){return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")";}) 
        .style("opacity", .8) 
        .html("try<br/>");;

  ;
});



</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `austinshapefiles/tract2.json` instead? That assumes that `austinshapefiles` is a subdirectory of the same `practice/code` directory as `austinmap.html`.

Comment: I tried d3.json("/austinshapefiles/tract2.json"....instead but still got a 404 error

Comment: Try without the `/` in front.

Comment: That didn't work either unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The thing is,

```
/path/to/file.json
```

is an absolute path and will likely resolve to

```
http://localhost:800/path/to/file.json
```

and

```
path/to/file.json
```

will resolve to

```
http://localhost:8000/documents/d3js_projects/practice/code/path/to/file.json
```

What directory are you serving exactly ?

---

**Edit :**
Okay so you're serving

```
C:\Users\garson
```

Your HTML file is

```
C:\Users\garson\Documents\d3js_projects\practice\code\austinmap.html
```

Your data file is located in

```
C:\Users\garson\Documents\d3js_projects\practice\code\austin‌​shapefiles\tract2.json
```

You're accessing the HTML file at

```
http://localhost:8000/documents/d3js_projects/practice/code/austinmap.html
```

which is fine and dandy, although there's a case difference that bothers me but it's probably a typo (documents !== Documents).

Then from this file, you're trying to reach

```
/practice/code/austinshapefiles/tract2.json
```

which resolves to

```
C:\Users\garson\practice\code\austinshapefiles\tract2.json
```

See ? That's the problem. You should try

```
d3.json("documents/d3js_projects/practice/code/austinshapefiles/tract2.json", ...
```

(please make sure to double check the case for "documents" though).

Comment: OK so in command prompt I ran: C:/Python27/python.exe -m SimpleHTTPServer from C:\Users\garson. The relevant files are saved in C:\Users\garson\Documents\d3js_projects\practice\code and C:\Users\garson\Documents\d3js_projects\practice\code\austinshapefiles